# execute() stucks after using Hibernate methods

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I have a DAO implementation of interaction with a DB via JDBC (UserDaoJDBCImpl ()) and via Hibernate (UserDaoHibernateImpl ()) separately. They have methods for creating (createUsersTable ()) and dropping (dropUsersTable ()) tables, which in both implementations are done through the statement.execute () method. Running through the JDBC implementation goes well. And the problem is the following: if after using the method with Hibernate tools (session, transaction) I create or delete a table, then statement.executeUpdate () will hang inside them. I think this is due to the fact that the resource did not close after using Hibernate, but I do not understand what exactly. Below are methods for creating, deleting, and one of the methods followed by kaput. And also [link to the github](https://github.com/enesan/CoreTaskTemplate/tree/master/src).

```
public void createUsersTable() {
    try (Statement statement = Util.connectDB().createStatement()) {
        // нужен ли здесь автоинкремент у айди, если он прописан в аннотации?
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User" +
                "(id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                "name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL," +
                "lastName VARCHAR(50)," +
                "age TINYINT(3))");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Create table exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void dropUsersTable() {
    try (Statement statement = Util.connectDB().createStatement()) {
        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Drop table exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void saveUser(String name, String lastName, byte age) {
        Session session = Util.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(new User(name, lastName, age));
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Also sessionFactory:

```
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb?useSSL=false";
private static final String USER = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "root";

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if(sessionFactory == null) {
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", URL);
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", USER);
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", PASSWORD);
            properties.setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                    .addProperties(properties).addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder =
                    new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Creating sessionFactory exception");
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Log of a successfully passed method before method with stuck:

```
мар. 09, 2021 10:26:17 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.0.Final}
мар. 09, 2021 10:26:17 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
мар. 09, 2021 10:26:17 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
мар. 09, 2021 10:26:17 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
мар. 09, 2021 10:26:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
мар. 09, 2021 10:26:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb?useSSL=false]
мар. 09, 2021 10:26:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
мар. 09, 2021 10:26:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
мар. 09, 2021 10:26:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
мар. 09, 2021 10:26:17 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
мар. 09, 2021 10:26:18 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Comment: What happens if you do not add any DB call in main method

Comment: @Acewin so everything is working good

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at your `Main.java` class, and it seems that your are using the `createUsersTable()` and `dropUsersTable()` at the launch of you application.

With JDBC, it's true that you have to deal with all these stuff, like the creation and dropping of table, if you needed.

Hibernate is a different thing, you don't have to *manually* drop or create table. If you really need to do that, there is a more efficient way to do that, by just adding the following property in your `getSessionFactory()` method:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
```

In this way, when the SessionFactory is created, the database tables will be dropped (if present) and re-created.

You can have a look at the [User guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl) for the possible values of the property.

I don't know the version of Hibernate you're using, but those values are valid for older version ones as well.

Comment: Adding to Marco's point that hibernate query engine does not allow execute on ddl.
Create and drop table is ddl

Comment: Indeed, that's the reason why in JDBC works and with Hibernate doesn't. @Enesan says that it gets stuck, but in my opinion it's hard to predict what happens internally.

Comment: Thanks for Answer, Marco. It was really useful for me. I'm using hibernate 5. But in my task said "Realise adding and dropping table in methods in UserDaoHibernateImpl using SQL". I think it means I must use JDBC tools for it. And one guy told me that there is wrong in my SessionFactory. But I tried different variants and there wasn't any other result

Comment: Yes indeed, DDL cannot be performed in Hibernate, thus you must use JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding transaction opening/closing to getAllUsers() method. I really didn't expected that problem could base there. Compiler didn't touch that point in anyway.